# mkvirtualenv command not found showing in my Git bash though I have done all the required steps

Tags: virtualenv, git-bash, virtualenvwrapper

I want to create virtual env for my project and once I am entering `mkvirtualenv profiles-api` in my git bash, It is showing *mkvirtualenv command not found*.

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~s mkvirtualenv profiles-rest-api --python=python3
mkvirtualenv not found
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly were those *required steps*?

Comment: I did vagrant up then vagrant ssh after that once the ubuntu server established I have entered mkvirtualenv profiles_api --python=python3

Comment: `mkvirtualenv` is not a program in Ubuntu, it's a function in `virtualenvwrapper`. You need to install and configure `virtualenvwrapper`. See https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html